# Python: Loop through two lists, adding to them if condition is met, but looping through every element of the list everytime

Tags: python

If I run this once, it will work and return success. Then, when the loop runs again, it will only check the last element of the lists. How do I do this such that the loop runs and checks every element of the list in the condition statement?

```
def draw():
    mesasX, mesasY = [], []
    x, y = random.randint(6,94), random.randint(6,94)
    mesasX.append(x)
    mesasY.append(y)
    for mesax, mesay in zip(mesasX, mesasY):
        x, y = random.randint(6,94), random.randint(6,94)
        if (x - 8 < mesax < x + 8 and y + 8 > mesay > y - 8):
            print("Failed")
        else:
            mesasX.append(x)
            mesasY.append(y)
            print("Success!")  
            break
```

Comment: you're modifying your list while iterating on it. Not the best design choice

Answer (score 3):

You want to compare every new item to every old item. The way to do this is to move the loops around. And use `all`:

```
def draw():
    mesasX, mesasY = [], []
    x, y = random.randint(6,94), random.randint(6,94)
    mesasX.append(x)
    mesasY.append(y)
    while True:
        x, y = random.randint(6,94), random.randint(6,94)
        if all(x - 8 < mesax < x + 8 and y + 8 > mesay > y - 8 
               for mesax, mesay in zip(mesasX, mesasY)):
            print("Failed")
        else:
            mesasX.append(x)
            mesasY.append(y)
            print("Success!")  
            break
```

This reads like this generate an item test if it fits if it doesn't try again if it does add it to the list and stop.

This can be made much faster if the list is replaced with a spacial index of 16 by 16 unit boxes centered at a point. This would permit one to turn the near by test into a point in box test which could be near constant time.

Then if one could uniformly sample from the union of these boxes that would remove the testing as every generated item would pass the test.